# How can I send a cookie via node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, node-fetch

I recently started to work with the roblox api, It's been going good so far but I can't login. I tried to set the cookie by doing `apiCall.headers.set-cookie = cookie`, But that doesn't seem to work. How can I solve this issue?

Would I have to get set-cookie then edit it? i.g

```js
const cookieSet = await apiCall.headers.get("set-cookie")
cookieSet = cookie
```

If I made it difficult to understand, I'll try to make it more clear
How would I post a cookie to a roblox API?

My code:

```js
    if (!cookie.startsWith("_|WARNING:")) {
        throw new Error("Make sure your token is correct")
    }
    const cookies = {
        headers: {
            cookie: cookie
        }
    }

    await fetch("https://www.roblox.com", cookies)
    const thing = await fetch('https://api.roblox.com/currency/balance', cookies).then(res => res.json())
    console.log(thing)
```

Thing outputs : `{ errors: [ { code: 403, message: 'Forbidden' } ] }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send cookies with node-fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815845/how-to-send-cookies-with-node-fetch)

Comment: Not really, I still get a 403 error.

Comment: What's the purpose of the cookie? Because a 403 would suggest an authorisation problem, meaning you don't have permissions to do what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm trying to get the users balance using a roblox API

Answer (score 1):

Well turns out I had to access the cookie from the Header. I did so by doing

```js
 const apiCall = await html.func("api.roblox.com/currency/balance", {
        headers: {
            cookie: `.ROBLOSECURITY=${cookie}`
        }
    })
```

Thanks for those who tried to help me!

Comment: Isn't that what the linked answer says?

Comment: Well, I didn't realize it until I kept staring at it.