# Set cookie by passing it to request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, fetch

The question may seem weird, but let me show what I mean:

[Here](https://docs.beeswax.com/docs/authentication), you post your credentials as the body of a post request, and then the response will somehow set a cookie that you passed into the header. It uses curl that I don't have any experience with, and trying to earn the same with node.
I was trying to set it as a variable, but it didn't work:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

let cookie = ''

const auth = () => fetch(
  `${URL}/rest/authenticate`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    headers: {
      cookie
    }
  }
);
```

I was searching for the same problem mentioned by someone else, but couldn't really find anything.

How can I set the cookies this way to a variable, or even a local file in node like in the example linked?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```js
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        cookie: 'accessToken=1234abc; userId=1234'
    }
};
const result = await fetch(`${URL}/rest/authenticate`, options);
```

Also, check out [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815845/how-to-send-cookies-with-node-fetch) on SO.