# Nextjs & custom Express server - cannot access cookie set with `http: true` in the express server

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, next.js

I am trying to parse a cookie which was set by including the property `httpOnly: true` on  my custom express server

Now in my NextJs app I can fetch the cookie in the server side method `getServerSideProps` and access the cookie in `ctx.req.cookies` from there. But when I make a fetch api call (from the server side method) to the custom server, the cookie does not seem to be accessible in the custom server api call.

Here is my `express` configuration in `server.ts`:

```
    // Express Configuration
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
    app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }))
    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

This is how I set the cookie on custom express server:

```
res.cookie('rtk', refreshTokenJWT.token, {
    httpOnly: true,
})
```

This is the fetch api call from `getServerSideProps` method:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/refresh_token', {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
})
```

Perhaps it is because of the fact that I have to make the api call with absolute url, when I try to do `fetch('/refresh_token', ...)` I get the error: `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`

I could possibly send the payload from the server side method in the `request body` and handle it in the custom express server, but this does not seem like the best solution.

pls elp, thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify, the `await fetch()` is happening in the server side method `getServerSideProps` of nextjs.

Sending the cookie as a header in the `fetch` api call as suggested by @O. Jones works, but I was under the impression that this wouldn't work since I had set `httpOnly: true`.

Comment: Please clarify by [edit]ing your question: is your `await fetch()` call in your node / express code, not your client-side code? If so, check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815845/how-to-send-cookies-with-node-fetch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815845/how-to-send-cookies-with-node-fetch works perfectly fine. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you. @O.Jones

Answer (score 0):

You have to, and are allowed to, parse that server response header despite the httponly attribute being present.

Why? Because [HttpOnly (owasp link)](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) is only an instruction to the browser that *it* should enforce that isolation; when your client code is just another node.js process, it's just a response header.

Here's the regurgitation I'm doing in my auth's unit testing that sounds very similar to your needs; I'm always getting exactly two cookies in comma-delimited one liner format, as emitted by my Koa RESTful app (your Express setup could be comma-delimited like this one, or send two Set-Cookies, so you may need a minor alteration if you have the latter case.)

```js
// raw's format is `koa.sess=YA5N/yI1KhKc/qyylgNduj8vK3e2; path=/; expires=Sun, 09 May 2021 05:17:19 GMT; secure; httponly, koa.sess.sig=8x1BraqjAvKryLx1fvgc0DBu5D4; path=/; expires=Sun, 09 May 2021 05:17:19 GMT; secure; httponly`;
const scp = require('set-cookie-parser');
const cookies = scp.parse(scp.splitCookiesString(headers['set-cookie']));
const next_request_headers = {
    cookie: cookies.map(cookie => cookie.name + '=' + cookie.value).join('; ')
};
```

I'm using [npm:set-cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-cookie-parser) because [cookies are jank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969232/what-are-allowed-characters-in-cookies) and I got fed up with handling commas in both expirations and delimiters.

### side issue: abs URLs

> TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Cookie domain rules are applied after relative URLs are normalized to absolute URLs, so it sounds to me like this side-issue is only about node-style fetches not having the implicit server/path needed for a browser-style relative ajax URL, and not blocking on anything to do with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**getServerSideProps**, by it's name, means it's generated **server side**

When you do a fetch in `getServerSideProps`, you do not have any *default* cookies.